# Composite Primary key - Generate sequence grouped by column

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I want to generate a sequence of numbers using only `spring/jpa` but they need to be grouped by some column.

As an example,
The entity name is `exampleEntity` which has two fields, which look like below:

|Code| No|
| -------- |--------|
| ABC | V1 |
| ABC | V2 |
| ABC | V3 |
| EFG | V1 |
| EFG | V2 |
I could only get a direct sequence, that is, `1,2,3,4,5` but not grouped by.
**(Code, No)** are composite Primary keys.
Code can be inserted as a new record.
I have created one `IdClass` for composite key and using the generated value on ID No in `exampleEntity`.

```
@Entity
@Table
@IdClass(...)
public Class Example {
@Id @Column
private Sting Code;

@Id @Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "XyzIdGenerator")
@GenericGenerator(name = "XyzIdGenerator",
    strategy = "com.mycompany.myapp.id.StringSequenceGenerator",
    parameters = {
        @Parameter(name = "StringSequenceGenerator.VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER", value = "V"),
@Parameter(name = "StringSequenceGenerator.NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER", value = "%01d")
    })
private String No
getter and setter...
```

Generator class:

```
public class StringSequenceGenerator extends SequenceStyleGenerator {

    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER = "valuePrefix";
    public static final String VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT = "";
    private String valuePrefix;

    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER = "numberFormat";
    public static final String NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT = "%d";
    private String numberFormat;

    @Override
    public Serializable generate(SharedSessionContractImplementor session,
                                 Object object) throws HibernateException {

        return valuePrefix + String.format(numberFormat,
                super.generate(session, object));
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(Type type, Properties params,
                          ServiceRegistry serviceRegistry) throws MappingException {

        super.configure(LongType.INSTANCE, params, serviceRegistry);
        valuePrefix = ConfigurationHelper.getString(VALUE_PREFIX_PARAMETER,
                params, VALUE_PREFIX_DEFAULT);
        numberFormat = ConfigurationHelper.getString(NUMBER_FORMAT_PARAMETER,
                params, NUMBER_FORMAT_DEFAULT);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should show us the code you use, without it we can't help you much.

Comment: Edited the post to include code.

Comment: Hi @Federico, how you manage to make it work ? Could you please suggest if any other way works for you?

Comment: @Darshana why are you asking me? I only tidied up the post a bit.

Comment: @Raghav, Above question is for you. Could you please check